# Boolean operation in Xpath: Using attributes

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Following is a snippet of .xml file. I did following :

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filesInDirectory.get(i));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr1 = xPath.compile("//codes[@ class ='class2']/code[@code]");
Object result1 = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) result1;
```

Now,

```
System.out.println("result length"+":"+nodes1.getLength());
returns 2.
```

I would like to make logical decision based on the attribute names, like(pseudocode)

```
 if(nodes1.contains(123))
```

or

```
if(nodes1.contains(123) && nodes1.contains(456))
   and make decision.
```

how would i do it?

```
<metadata>
   <codes class="class1">
     <code code="ABC">
         <detail "blah" "blah">
     </code>
  </codes>
  <codes class="class2">
    <code code="123">
        <detail "blah blah"/>
    </code>
    <code code="456">
        <detail "blah blah"/>
    </code>
  </codes>
 </metadata>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
        File f = new File("test.xml");
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        InputSource src = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(f));
        Object result = xpath.evaluate("//codes[@class='class2']/code/@code",src,XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList lst = (NodeList)result;

        List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int idx=0; idx<lst.getLength(); idx++){
            codeList.add(lst.item(idx).getNodeValue());
        }
        if(codeList.contains("123")){
            System.out.println("123");
        }

        if(codeList.contains("123") && codeList.contains("456")){
            System.out.println("123 and 456");
        }
```

***Explanation:***

XPath `//codes[@class='class2']/code/@code` will collect all `code` values under `codes` with having class as `class2`. 
You can then build a `List` from `NodeList` so that you can use `contains()` method.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
XPathExpression expr1 = xPath.compile("//codes[@class]");
Object result1 = expr1.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) result1;
```

should return you a list of elements with a `class` attribute. Iterate over this node list and `foreach` node extract the `[@code]` element and use a check like

```
if (node.getNodeValue().equals("123"))
```

to establish whether your node has the value you are looking for.

Comment: there is no method  called **getNodeValue** for the object **NodeList**

Comment: Nope there sure isn't. But there is a method `item(int index)` that returns a Node and I'm assuming you know how for loops work ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
/*/codes[@class]/code[@code = '123' or @code = '456']
```

It selects any `code` element whose `code` attribute's string value is one of the strings `"123"` or `"456"` and that (the `code` element) is a child of a `codes` element that has a `class attribute and is a child of the top element of the XML document.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/codes[@class]/code[@code = '123' or @code = '456']"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<metadata>
    <codes class="class1">
        <code code="ABC">
            <detail/>
        </code>
    </codes>
    <codes class="class2">
        <code code="123">
            <detail />
        </code>
        <code code="456">
            <detail />
        </code>
    </codes>
</metadata>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<code code="123">
   <detail/>
</code>
<code code="456">
   <detail/>
</code>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the standard XPath operator **[`or`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-OrExpr)**.